# Having trouble finding the right JSON path for android project

Tags: java, android, json, xml

```
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);

JSONObject responseObj = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");

JSONArray resultArray = responseObj.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i =0;i<resultArray.length();i++){

String sectionName = resultArray.getString("sectionName");}
```

I want to get the section name for this url:
https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=e11b8d10-d6ef-4fb7-9c12-094c58d37687

Comment: Can't understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Json Value Like this.

```
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);

    JSONObject responseObj = null;
    try {
        responseObj = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray resultArray = responseObj.getJSONArray("results");
        int size = resultArray.length();

        for (int i =0;i<size;i++){
            JSONObject myJson = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String sectionName = myJson.getString("sectionName");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```